# Infinite While loop in Vivado

Tags: embedded

Here is what I am exactly working on:
I have to run an infinite `while` loop and check the output on oscilloscope. As I change the processor frequency, I will get a change in the period of output square wave time-period, right?
And that is what I have to achieve.
What is wrong with writing the program in below mentioned way in Vivado?
I am working with ZYNQ zc702 evaluation board and Vivado HDL.
Following is the code that I have written:

```
module validation(
    output a
);


reg a1 = 0;

assign a = a1;

integer counter = 0;

while(1) // Infinite While Loop
begin
    counter <= counter + 1; //The counter goes up.
    if(counter == 0)
    begin
        a1 <= ~a1;           //If the counter reaches 1000, toggle the output.
        counter <= 1000;     // Resetting the counter.
    end
end


endmodule
```

Comment: Your question is confusing which gives me the impression you have no idea what an HDL languages is or does: .You talk about a processor but the code is Verilog. There is no "processor" in you code, nor is there a clock. I suspect you need to read up on HDL. Start with looking for examples how to make a counter.

Comment: @Oldfart, yes you are right, this is my first exposure to HDL. By processor, I mean I will change the frequency of operation  of zynq zc702 processor in Vivado using IP block. And I am expecting that the time to count to 1000 will also change accordingly. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean I will change the frequency of operation of zynq zc702 processor in Vivado using IP block. And I am expecting that the time to count to 1000 will also change accordingly.

Nope! What you have is some vague Verilog code (which by the way does not work) but which has nothing to do whatsoever with what the Zynq processor(s) do.

Your HDL and processor are two completely different entities and have nothing to do with each other. (Not until you make some hardware which connects the two using e.g. an AXI bus. But you are miles away from that.)

Basically you must:

- Instance a Zynq core with a clock coming out.
- Write a counter in Verilog which toggles an output. (About a million example out there)
- Connect the clock of your counter to the Zynq output clock.
- Connect the counter toggle output to a spcific pin of the FPGA package using placing constraints.
- Synthesis and watch the pin with a scope.

Best way to start at all the above is to read-up on Verilog for the counter.
As to Zynq: look at some youtube video's about how to use the Zynq and Vivado. (That is how I started with Zynq too)

Comment: You want them to connect an output of the FPGA fabric to an output of the processor?

Comment: @ThePhoton I am curious how I gave that impression. I said "specific pin of the FPGA package" which is not an output of the processor. In fact the Vivado 'block manager' will not let you connect two outputs together.

Comment: I'm responding to the part where you said, "Connect the clock of your counter to the Zynq output clock." Isn't the "clock of your counter" an output of the FPGA fabric? And isn't the "Zynq output clock" an output of the processor? (I don't think a pin of the package is involved here)

Comment: OK, now I think I get what you meant. The "clock of the counter" is an input to the counter logic?

Comment: Yes, HDL counters tend to have clock inputs :-)  I admit it was a bit terse but the whole she-bang would take a few pages to explain.